# Android- Running my application on 2.1 and higher versions

Tags: android

I want to make application that support 2.1 or higher platforms. Does anyone have solution for it?
Can I use somekind of cross-platform for it or cross-platefroms are only for porting applications from differnt OS? Or there is any library i can use for this purpose?

Answer (score 0):

Any application built with Android 2.1 API will work later versions of Android (theoretically).  In the AndroidManifest.xml file, set the target SDK version to 2.1, and the 2.1 API will be loaded by Eclipse for the application.  Done.  It's still recommended to test it on later versions in case there's some slight variations that aren't documented, but most if not all things should work.

Comment: I make one application in Adroid 2.2 but when I run that application on 2.3.3. It does't work. There is somekind of paring error.

Comment: @user1161518: If you had issues, please post error log messages.

Answer (score 0):

Just code your application and in your AndroidManifest put this somewhere `<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" />`.

That corresponds to Android 2.1, more details here http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/api-levels.html

Comment: yes you right for API Level you can study this things will be clear for you.